# how turn off browser sync in sublime text 3?

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, sublimetext3, npm-live-server

I'm using Sublime Text 3 and installed browsersync package for live reloading.
When I quit from Sublime and close liveserver app in my browser and try to open new liveserver with react start command I get a message that say: "Something is already running on port 3000." Then I check localhost:3000 and the browser still sync to Sublime I don't know how to turn off liveserver in port 3000 ?
[image]

please help me

Answer (score 1):

I assume that [this](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Browser%20Sync) is the plugin you're using. Unfortunately, the plugin has been abandoned for 5 years, and the way it's written, there is no method for killing the node server once you're done with the plugin. From the Windows command line, this:

```
taskkill /im node-windows.exe /f /t
```

should do the trick, but you'll have to run it manually. Alternatively, you can use Task Manager to kill any `node-windows.exe` processes.

Comment: i am use sublime text packages for live server and the name of the package is browserSync i am install NO plugin or extension in my browser but when i am done with my sublime text and i close browser and sublime text and after while open the browser strangly eanough still liveserver from sublime text is runnig

Comment: @reza I understand all that, and I gave you the solution in my answer. BrowserSync is a Sublime Text plugin, not a browser plugin. In order to stop the liveserver from running, you need to run the command I gave you in the command prompt. There's no other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to kill the service is going to
Start -> Resource Monitor -> Network
Under "Listening Ports" check for your port number, in this case 3000.
Take the process Id and then look for it under "Processes with Network Activity"
Check the process and right click -> End Process.

This will end the process utilizing the port 3000.

Answer (score 0):

Try using <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> on your keyboard in your terminal or your command line (depending on whether your operating system is Unix based or Windows based). PowerShell should work too, if on a PC.

Comment: The terminal is closed but the BroserSync is still running.